# R plot, how to start y at non zero?

Tags: r, plot

I have a set of data which goes from: `8e41` to ~ `1e44`. I want to plot starting at 1e41 on the y-axis, however using the argument: `ylim=c(1e41,1e45)` does not work for me.

Here is the minimally reproducible code:

```
x = c(1,2)
y = c(1e41,1e44)
plot(x,y,ylim=c(1e41,1e45))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 1e41 is so much closer to 0 than 1e45 that it's virtually the same.  Have you considered working on the log scale?

```
plot(x,y,ylim=c(1e41,1e45), log = 'y')
```

or even

```
plot(x, y, log = 'y')
```

Think of this another way - rescale your data by dividing your range by 1e41: `c(8e41, 1e44)/ 1e41` - you get 8 and 1000.  Is there any significant difference between starting the scale at 0 (or 1) versus 8?  If you chose to divide by 1e40 instead, you're looking at 80 and 10,000.  Try the following code to see this:

```
m <- 1e41 # change this as desired
plot(x, y / m)
abline(h = c(0, 1e41 / m))
```

By changing `m`, the only thing that changes is the numbers on the y-axis, the relative positions do not change.  Look at how close 0 and 8e41 are, and you'll see why it really doesn't matter whether or not the plot starts at 0 versus 1e41.  As a fraction of the total height of the plot, the difference is 1/1000.

### Changing the values at which the axis is labeled

Here's one more option for you - changing the values at which the plot is marked.  That requires two steps - first, removing the axis labels when the plot is originally created, then adding in the ones you actually want:

```
plot(x, y, yaxt = 'none')
axis(2, c(1e41, seq(1e43, 1e44, 1e43)))
```

Comment: I don't want a log scale because this plot will be compared to other plots in literature.

Comment: I expanded on my answer to make the difference more clear.  Not working on the log scale is fine, but I think the size of your numbers is masking their relationship when plotted.  Hopefully the expansion makes this more clear.

Comment: Thank you. I know about scaling the axis. But, that does not really answer what I would live to have the graph to be; what I want is to start at 1e41, not zero. Sorry that I will have to down vote.

Comment: Are you just trying to change the values at which the axis is labeled?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say. How about show me the code you think it is and go from there? Thank you.

Comment: Did you see the edit to my code?  (look under the text in bold face).

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. That trick you are suggesting, it can reproduce the minimal example I mentioned, but it is not generalized enough for the real data. Try this:

    x = c(1,2,3,4)
    y = c(1e41,1e44,1e42,1e39)
    plot(x, y, yaxt = 'none')

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
x = c(1,2)
y = c(1e41,1e44)
data = data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=log(y))) + geom_point() + ylim(90,150)
```

I think you should use the log of y, as it shows the same data.

Comment: Yeah, I know that ggplot can do that. But, I would like to know how to work with base R plot. Thanks.